# Google App Engine - Flask Application Bypassing Standard Google Auth on Devserver

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, flask

I am new to Flask and I am trying to organize my code as a large application for deployment on Google App Engine.  I am using [Flask-Classy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/) to help organize my application into logical packages.

The application runs on the dev server just fine with one exception.  When I set `login: required` or `login: admin` in my `app.yaml` (see app.yaml below), the application appears to skip over the mock Google Login page and automatically signs in as 'test@example.com'.

Normally, I would expect to see the standard Google mock authentication form (below) when login:required or login: admin is set in the app.yaml.  However, when I point the browser to the '/' or any other uri, I am directed right to the respective page without authenticating via this form.
[image: Google mock authentication form]

I am not sure what I am missing/doing wrong. I am not getting any type of errors.

Below, I have included my application's structure and most of the pertinent code to see if anyone might be able to point out anything I am doing wrong here.

```
/flask_app
  /flask_app
    /mod_one
      /__init__.py
      /forms.py
      /views.py
      /models.py
    /mod_two
      /__init__.py
      /forms.py
      /views.py
      /models.py
    /static
      /css
      ...
    /templates
      /index.html
      ...
    /__init__.py
    /settings.py
    /urls.py
  /lib
  /app.yaml
  /appengine_config.py
  /main.py
```

app.yaml

```
application: flask-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "30d"

builtins:
  - deferred: on
  - admin_redirect: on

handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: flask_app/static/css

- url: /admin/.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  login: required
```

appengine_config.py

```
import sys
import os.path

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

main.py

```
from flask_app import app

app = app
```

flask_app/**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication


app = Flask(__name__)

if os.getenv('FLASK_CONF') == 'TEST':
    app.config.from_object('flask_app.settings.Testing')

elif 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' in os.environ and os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev'):
    # Development settings
    app.config.from_object('flask_app.settings.Development')  

    app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, evalex=True)

else:
    app.config.from_object('flask_app.settings.Production')

# Instantiate Flask-Bootstrap.
Bootstrap(app)

import urls
```

flask_app/urls.py

```
from flask import render_template
from flask_app import app


@app.route('/')
def index():
    params = {
        'page_title': 'Home'
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **params)


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    params = {
        'page_title': 'Contact'
    }
    return render_template('contact.html', **params)


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    params = {
        'page_title': 'About'
    }
    return render_template('about.html', **params)


# Error handlers
# Handle 404 errors
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404


# Handle 500 errors
@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500

# Register Flask Classy Classes
import mod_one.views as mod_one
import mod_two.views as mod_two

mod_one.OneView.register(app)
mod_two.TwoView.register(app)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not already logged-in? If you go to /_ah/login, click 'log out' and then try again what happens?

Comment: @Greg - That worked!  However, I am still baffled that upon running the application in the dev_server for the first and subsequent times that it did not ever redirect to the mock login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Greg pointed out in a comment to the question, I was already 'logged in' to the dev_appserver (which threw me off since I never saw the mock login page) so authentication was happening using the default 'test@example.com' user.

Once I went to `/_ah/login` I was able to access the mock login page and proceed as usual from there.